# Python to C++: From Deriv, to Base, to Deriv again

Tags: c++, python, boost

I'm using Boost.Python to expose my C++ code to Python. I've encountered a difficulty related to having an object passed from one language to the other multiple times. Here's what I want to do:

### The C++ code

```
class Base
{
  public:
    void baseTest() {
        std::cout << "Base::basetest()";
    }
};

class Deriv
    : public Base
{
  public:
    void derivTest() {
        std::cout << "Deriv::derivTest()";
    }
};

void call(Base& b, boost::python::object func)
{
    func(b);
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(event)
{
    using namespace boost;
    using namespace boost::python;

    class_<Base>("Base")
        .def("baseTest", &Base::baseTest)
    ;

    class_<Deriv, bases<Base>>("Deriv")
        .def("derivTest", &Deriv::derivTest)
    ;

    def("call", call);
}
```

### Python code

```
from event import *

def callback(deriv):
    deriv.baseTest() # works fine
    deriv.derivTest() # crash!

def run():
    d = Deriv()
    call(d, callback)
```

### What I want to happen

1. C++: Calls the `run()` function defined in Python. (No problem here)
2. Python: `run()` creates a new `Deriv` object; it passes it and a function object, `callback`, back to C++, through the `call` function. (Also okay)
3. C++: `call()` takes the `Deriv` object as a `Base&`. It passes the Base-reference to the Python callback it received through the second parameter.
4. Python: The callback receives the `Base` object from C++. However, it expects it to be a `Deriv`: if I call `derivTest()` the program crashes. However, if I call `baseTest()`, it doesn't crash.

How can I make the callback not crash?

Comment: *maybe* (I don't know enough to be sure), you should make `baseTest` virtual (and also add a virtual destructor).

Comment: `baseTest ` doesn't need to be virtual because it is not overridden.

Comment: @Alexandre, Mike: It indeed makes no sense to make `baseTest` virtual. Adding *anything* virtual (which should probably be destructor) might help though, because having virtual method is what allows C++ runtime to check runtime types.

Comment: @Jan: oh, I read too fast... However, my initial though was that RTTI was not possible because your class is not polymorphic (hence the crash). But you would have gotten a compiler message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the comments, I found the solution to this. It's actually quite simple, you just have to wrap the Base object in a shared_ptr instead of passing it by reference, like this:

```
void call(boost::shared_ptr<Base> b, boost::python::object func)
{
    func(b);
}
```

But be careful about something. I tried to used std::shared_ptr that comes with Visual C++ 2010 Express (the 'memory' header) and it caused a crash. I had to use the boost::shared_ptr for it to work. (I'm using version 1.46.1 of Boost.)